# postgresql updated to 10 - but systemctl start postgresql starts 9.3

Tags: upgrade, systemd, postgresql

How do I make sure that it's version 10 that is started by systemd - not 9.3

I've looked in `/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service` but there's no version information in there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a specific systemctl start postgres@10-main works after the port has been fixed in /etc/postgres/10/main/postgresql.conf from 5435 to 5432 and vice versa with 9.3 conf. I'll import the old dbs, and apt remove postgres 9.3.

I presume everything will just work after that, right?

[edit]
Everything did just work after that.

Comment: The Postgresql 10 install uses a different port so you can verify that everything is working before removing the old Postgresql on the default port 5432.